# PHP if in array, do something with the value

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I am trying to check if a value is in an array. If so, grab that array value and do something with it. How would this be done?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
$the_array = array("buejcxut->10", "jueofi31->20", "nay17dtt->30");

if (in_array('20', $the_array)) {

    // If found, assign this value to a string, like $found = 'jueofi31->20'

    $found_parts = explode('->', $found);

    echo $found_parts['0']; // This would echo "jueofi31"    

}
```

Comment: if your array is built like so: `"buejcxut->10"` it will be more complicated. The array should be like: `"buejcxut"=>10`

Comment: in_array only provide the true or false according to the searched result, you need a different logic to get the searched value. Try the array_walk() and in_array together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
foreach($the_array as $key => $value) {
    if(preg_match("#20#", $value)) {
        $found_parts = explode('->', $value);
    }
    echo $found_parts[0];
}
```

And replace "20" by any value you want.

Answer (score 1):

you might be better off checking it in a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($the_array as $key => $value) {
  if ($value == 20) {
    // do something
  }
  if ($value == 30) {
    //do something else
  }
}
```

also you array definitition is strange, did you mean to have:

```
$the_array = array("buejcxut"=>10, "jueofi31"=>20, "nay17dtt"=>30);
```

using the array above the $key is the element key (buejcxut, jueofi31, etc) and $value is the value of that element (10, 20, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can search the values of arrays with Regular Expressions.

```
<?php

$the_array = array("buejcxut->10", "jueofi31->20", "nay17dtt->30");

$items = preg_grep('/20$/', $the_array);

if( isset($items[1]) ) {

    // If found, assign this value to a string, like $found = 'jueofi31->20'

    $found_parts = explode('->', $items[1]);

    echo $found_parts['0']; // This would echo "jueofi31"    

}
```

You can see a demo here: http://codepad.org/XClsw0UI

Answer (score 0):

if you want to define an indexed array it should be like this:

```
$my_array = array("buejcxut"=>10, "jueofi31"=>20, "nay17dtt"=>30);
```

then you can use in_array

```
if (in_array("10", $my_array)) {
    echo "10 is in the array"; 
    // do something
}
```